# Use an Beaglebone Black LCD 4 Display with an Python GUI

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, beagleboneblack, lcd

I have Angstrom installed on my Beaglebone.
The Display that I'm using is the 4DCAPE-43T.

And I wrote a simple Python script with QT Desingner, to make an simple GUI program.

Now I want this program to run on the Beaglebone's LCD 4 Display.
How can I do that?

The only way I find to run the program was, over ssh on my laptop display.
Thanks if some one has an idea.

Comment: Python nor Qt have anything to do with your display, you need to install a desktop environment in your BeagleBone OS (debian/ubuntu I suppose), there are workarounds to run applications without a full desktop environment, but you still need Xorg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the qte enabled angstrom toolchain from this link "http://web.archive.org/web/20130823131954/http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/toolchains/".
Setup the QT IDE on your desktop to cross compile QT apps for BBB. 
Once you get binaries compatible with BBB architecture you can run them on BBB.
You need to look into cross-compilation stuff.